# How to improve this jquery and hide on focus out

Tags: jquery, hide, show

i have a simple search form than hide and show when click on button but i don't know how to hide when lose focus and i want to know how to improve the code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".search-toggle__icon").on({
        click: function() {
            $(".search-toggle__inner").toggleClass("is-hidden is-visible");
            $(".search-toggle .input-text").focus();
        }
    })
});
```

[here the demo](http://codepen.io/ensk/pen/JYPBVE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `blur` event of jQuery to detect when `.input-text` loses focus and toggle the class for `.search-toggle__inner` accordingly.

```
$(".input-text").on("blur", function() {
  $(".search-toggle__inner").toggleClass("is-visible is-hidden");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add an `focusout` event listener on the element. So your complete code should look like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".search-toggle__icon").on({
        click: function() {
            $(".search-toggle__inner").toggleClass("is-hidden is-visible");
            $(".search-toggle .input-text").focus();
        }
    });
    $(".search-toggle .input-text").on('focusout', function() {
        $(".search-toggle__inner").toggleClass("is-hidden is-visible");
    });
});
```

Comment: blur and focusout work well but when click on the button to show the form the same button can't close because the two events are trigger...i think to add a class to the button to identify his state .is-active .is-disable but doesn't work update the [pen](http://codepen.io/ensk/pen/JYPBVE)